# Is my divorce valid if we signed a handwritten paper with no witnesses?

Tags: talaq

Due to problems in my marriage my husband at times was not providing for me or my kids or practising Islam. I decided to ask for divorce after many attempts to fix my marriage.

I wrote on paper to him saying "I divorce you" three times. He signed it and I signed it. He didn't say it and he says at times he felt pressured and didn't want to give it me. There were no witnesses at the time of signing the letter. It was hand written not, an official one.

That was nearly 6 years ago. He since has married again but he says he has been told that our nikkah is still valid. He still wants me as his wife and wants to reconcile.

I don't believe we are still married. I haven't remarried and have been on my own since our spilt. Is the divorce valid?

Comment: "*I wrote on paper him saying I divorce u three times and he signed it and I signed it.*" this requires details and questions about talaq should be addressed at a well versed scholar, mainly this would first ask the husband. We are not a fatwa site.

Answer (score 1):

Assalm o Alaikum.
My sister Talaq is valid in this case... When husband sends a written talaq to his wife or signs a written paper, talaq becomes valid.
عن حماد قال: إذا کتب الرجل إلی امرأته -إلی- أمابعد! فأنت طالق فهي طالق، وقال ابن شبرمة: هي طالق". (المصنف لابن أبي شیبة، کتاب الطلاق، باب في الرجل یکتب طلاق امرأته بیده، مؤسسة علوم القرآن ۹/۵۶۲، رقم: ۱۸۳۰۴
Also I want to add there is nothing to regret after talaq is imposed. Talaq becomes valid in anger as well as in joke.
Jzk

Comment: In the given case he was given a text to sign. And as you may read [here](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/125215/does-signing-a-divorce-paper-count-as-divorce) the answer is not that simple nor straight forward.